# maximum number of files/directories handled by dirent struct

Tags: c

I have a directory (let's call it directory A) which contains ~15000 directories (B1,B2,..,B15000), each directory of the B's includes a file(let's call it "raw") which I want to read.
so I want to read: 
A/B1/raw
A/B2/raw
...

I don't know the B's directories names in advance, but I know the name of directory A and that it each B's directory there is a file called raw.

So I used dirent in order to opendir A and move over all the directories in it - extracting the name which contained in d_name field, but the run is stopped after I read the names of 264 directories!!

I wonder if the struct dirent cannot hold more than 264 directories ? Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advanced.

---

[Code from comment]

```
DIR* dRoot = opendir(argv[1]);
assert(dRoot != NULL);
struct dirent* dir;

while((dir = readdir(dRoot)))
{
    //suppose dirName is a string "argv[1]/dir->d_name/raw"
    FILE* file = fopen(dirName,"r");

    //do something

    fclose(file);
}

closedir(dRoot);
```

Comment: *How* do you read the directories? Can you please show us some code? Preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: DIR* dRoot = opendir(argv[1]);
assert(dRoot != NULL);
struct dirent* dir;
while((dir = readdir(dRoot))) {
  //suppose dirName is a string "argv[1]/dir->d_name/raw"
  FILE* file = fopen(dirName,"r");
  //do something
  fclose(file);
}
closedir(dRoot);

what I see is that I get out this loop although I didn't go over all the directories that rely in dRoot! seems like "dir->d_name" contains NULL after the directory number 264!

Comment: I assume you check for the current and parent directories (the ones named `"."` and `".."`)? Also, what is the argument to the program (`argv[1]`)? You check that the file opened properly (i.e. `file` is not `NULL`)? You check that it's a directory and not a file? And how do you create and initialize `dirName`?

Comment: The problem isn't the number of directories.  You might have an issue closing the files; you might be running out of space in your program; you might not be checking that you've successfully opened the file; you might be running into all sorts of issues.  But there is no specific upper limit on the size of directory that `readdir()` can read.

Answer (score 2):

`readdir()` allocates memory for every `struct dirent` it returns a pointer to. The `dirent`s are deallocated automatically on `closedir()`, so you can't `free()` that memory when you no longer need any *particular* `dirent`, and you can't use any `dirent` after `closedir()`. I suppose it's possible (though not likely) that your program can't allocate more memory for `dirent`s.
You could check `errno` after `readdir()` returns NULL to find out.

If that is the problem, you can instead use `readdir_r()`, which uses a `dirent*` to an allocation you provide (which could even be a local variable on the stack), and you could reuse it for all `dirent`s, one after the other. One caveat with `readdir_r()` is that the size of `struct dirent` depends on the file system, and you need to ensure your allocation is big enough.